# How to remove literals from input mask after form submit?

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, maskedinput

I'm using Josh Bush's MaskedInput plugin for jQuery in an ASP.NET 3.5 Webform app.

How to get rid from the literals in the code-behind file after form submit?

E.g: a phone input with the mask `$("#txtPhone").mask("(99)9999-9999");`

In the code-behind:

```
string customerPhone = txtPhone.Text
```

Which returns me: `(12)3456-7890`

But this is what I want: `1234567890`

In the [plugins changelog page](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) it says I can use `mask()` method with no arguments to archieve this. But how to do it from the code-behind?!

**EDIT**

My question wasn't clear, so: I want to send to the server the unmasked value. How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set removeMaskOnSubmit as true when you initialize the inputmask

```
    $("#txtPhone").inputmask({removeMaskOnSubmit: true});
```

Or we can get the unmasked value using this

```
$("#txtPhone").inputmask('unmaskedvalue');
```

Comment: is this solution even for the same plugin?  My version of the digitalBush mask (1.4.1) does not have a .inputmask() function on jquery collections.

Answer (score 2):

```
customerPhone = new string(customerPhone.ToCharArray()
                             .Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 1):

What I'm doing right now is, using the `submitHandler` (Validation plugin) to reset the input value, like this:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $("#txtPhone").val($("#txtPhone").mask());
    form.submit();
},
```

This solves the problem *BUT* smells really bad...

Answer (score 0):

You can strip out non-numeric characters with Regular Expressions in .NET, like this:

```
customerPhone = Regex.Replace(customerPhone, "[^0-9]", "");
```